# What does the -d in this cURL command mean?

Tags: xml, api, rest, curl, get

I'm working on a program that's making calls to a RESTful api.  All of the documentation for the api is cURL commands, but I can't make cURL commands, so I need to translate them and make the request a different way.  This is the example code they provide for the kind of query I want to make.

```
curl -u '{userEmail}:{userApiToken}' -v -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -o 'result.xml' -d '<request><layout>1</layout><searchmode>Cany</searchmode><searchvalue>aaron</searchvalue><filtermode></filtermode><filtervalue></filtervalue><special></special><limit>100</limit><start></start><sortfield></sortfield><sortdir></sortdir></request>' https://secure.website.com/contacts  `
```

I've been over the cURL documentation and understand all of the flags except for the -d.  I get that its argument is xml of search parameters, but what does the -d mean on a GET cURL?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`-d` specifies the body of the request. From the man-page:

> -d, --data 
>     (HTTP)  Sends  the  specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has
>   filled in an HTML form and presses
>     the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Compare to -F, --form.
>
> -d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. --data-raw is almost the same but does not have a special interpretation of  the  @ 
>   character.  To  post  data  purely
>    binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option.  To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.

It is interesting that you use a service that uses GET with request bodies, as explained [here, it is possible but unwanted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/3749523).

For example; proxies are allowed to remove the body. But as long as there are no machines between you and their server, it might work; and they probably have software that allows them to interpret the body.

Comment: That's what I thought.  But I didn't think GET requests had bodies.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: I've expanded my answer