# Curl unexpected token when using -d command

Tags: curl, post

```
curl.exe -k -H "Token:THisisarealtoken123" -H "Content-type:application/json" "https://api.deftesla.com/data_export" -X POST  '{
    "status" : ["sudan"],
    "export_settings" : {
        "format": "json",
        "model": "modelX"
    }
}'
```

getting unexpected token at '{\n    status : [sudan],\n    export_settings : {\n        format: json,\n        model: modelX\n    }\n}'"}

I've tried having it one line and still same error just no \n are in the error message. Am I forgetting a ' or " somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Add a -d flag before the post data and check. The syntax error disappears for me.

```sh
curl -k -H "Token:THisisarealtoken123" -H "Content-type:application/json" "https://api.deftesla.com/data_export" -X POST -d '{
    "status" : ["sudan"],
    "export_settings" : {
        "format": "json",
        "model": "modelX"
    }
}'
```

Helpful link to know more about the -d flag: [What does the -d in this cURL command mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701551/what-does-the-d-in-this-curl-command-mean/32701859)

Comment: I actually forgot the d in the code the error came from it with the -d. Still getting the error.